# Cannot solve Hungarian Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, hungarian-algorithm

I'm trying to implementing a function to solve the [hungarian algorithm](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Hungarian-Algorithm) and i think that there is something i have misunderstood about the algorithm.

For testing purposes i'm using this c++ [code](https://code.google.com/p/hungarian-cpp/) from google that is supposed to work.

But when i test this 14x11 matrix, it says that **it is not possible to solve**:

> [    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     ]
>
> [   53   207   256   207   231   348   348   348   231   244   244     ]
>
> [  240    33    67    33    56   133   133   133    56    33    33     ]
>
> [  460   107   200   107   122   324   324   324   122    33    33     ]
>
> [  167   340   396   340   422   567   567   567   422   442   442     ]
>
> [  167   367   307   367   433   336   336   336   433   158   158     ]
>
> [  160    20    37    20    31    70    70    70    31    22    22     ]
>
> [  200   307   393   307   222   364   364   364   222   286   286     ]
>
> [   33   153   152   153   228   252   252   252   228    78    78     ]
>
> [   93   140   185   140    58   118   118   118    58    44    44     ]
>
> [    0     7    22     7    19    58    58    58    19     0     0     ]
>
> [   67   153   241   153   128   297   297   297   128    39    39     ]
>
> [   73   253   389   253   253   539   539   539   253    36    36     ]
>
> [  173   267   270   267   322   352   352   352   322   231   231     ]

C++ code for creating the array: (in case someone wants to test it by using the  C++ example i provided)

> int r[14*11] ={0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  53,  207,  256,  207,  231,  348,  348,  348,  231,  244,  244,  240,  33,  67,  33,  56,  133,  133,  133,  56,  33,  33,  460,  107,  200,  107,  122,  324,  324,  324,  122,  33,  33,  167,  340,  396,  340,  422,  567,  567,  567,  422,  442,  442,  167,  367,  307,  367,  433,  336,  336,  336,  433,  158,  158,  160,  20,  37,  20,  31,  70,  70,  70,  31,  22,  22,  200,  307,  393,  307,  222,  364,  364,  364,  222,  286,  286,  33,  153,  152,  153,  228,  252,  252,  252,  228,  78,  78,  93,  140,  185,  140,  58,  118,  118,  118,  58,  44,  44,  0,  7,  22,  7,  19,  58,  58,  58,  19,  0,  0,  67,  153,  241,  153,  128,  297,  297,  297,  128,  39,  39,  73,  253,  389,  253,  253,  539,  539,  539,  253,  36,  36,  173,  267,  270,  267,  322,  352,  352,  352,  322,  231,  231};

If I run my implementation to reduce the number of zeros (so they can get covered by the minimum number of lines- step 9 in wikihow's link provided at the top -) I get the following matrix where i have to find the 0 combination unique for row and column.

**The problem is that it is impossible to solve** since  the columns 10 and 11 (the ones bold) only have one 0 each one and it is in the same row.

> Row 1 : [ 240 140 225 140 206 339 339 339 206 **215 215** 0   0   0   ]
>
> Row 2 : [ 254 0   37  0   43  58  58  58  43  **38  38**  67  67  67  ]
>
> Row 3 : [ 0   107 158 107 151 206 206 206 151 **182 182** 0   0   0   ]
>
> Row 4 :  [ 0   253 245 253 304 235 235 235 304 **402 402** 220 220 220 ]
>
> Row 5 :  [ 300 27  56  27  11  0   0   0   11  **0   0**   227 227 227 ]
>
> Row 6 :  [ 300 0   145 0   0   230 230 230 0   **284 284** 227 227 227 ]
>
> Row 7 :  [ 80  120 188 120 176 269 269 269 176 **193 193** 0   0   0   ]
>
> Row 8 :  [ 207 0   0   0   151 143 143 143 151 **96  96**  167 167 167 ]
>
> Row 9 :  [ 229 9   95  9   0   110 110 110 0   **159 159** 22  22  22  ]
>
> Row 10 : [ 147 0   40  0   148 221 221 221 148 **171 171** 0   0   0   ]
>
> Row 11 : [ 240 133 203 133 187 282 282 282 187 **215 215** 0   0   0   ]
>
> Row 12 : [ 189 3   0   3   94  58  58  58  94  **192 192** 16  16  16  ]
>
> Row 13 : [ 367 87  36  87  153 0   0   0   153 **379 379** 200 200 200 ]
>
> Row 14 : [ 194 0   82  0   11  115 115 115 11  **112 112** 127 127 127 ]

**Is there any kind of limitation with this method?** Or is just me, making a bad implementation of the algorithm? In this case, why "is the supposed to work" example not working either?

Any suggestion would be appreciate, or if you know any trick or suggestion to help finding the minimum number of lines to cover zeros, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there any kind of limitation with this method?**
Yes. That line drawing method will only properly work if you have made the maximum number of assignments at each step. <del>I don't particularly feel like working this out by hand to prove it, but I assume that the code you are using does not accomplish that for this particular matrix.</del> I decided to work it out (aka procrastinate) as best as I can figure from the lack of documentation, and it doesn't actually have a problem with covering all zeroes with the minimum number of lines. It's just bad at making assignments.

Every implementation of the Hungarian Algorithm I have found online will not work. They unfortunately all copy each other without actually learning the math behind it, and thus they all get it wrong. I have implemented something similar to what Munkres describes in his article "Algorithms for the Assignment and Transportation Problems", published in 1957. My code gives the results: (0,1), (1,3), (2,8), (3,2), (9,12), (10,11), (4,9), (8,7), (5,10), (6,6), (7,0) for a minimum cost of 828.

You can view my code here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/1yss74lxb7kro2p/APS.h

ps: Thanks for providing that C++ array. I wasn't looking forward to typing it myself.

pps: Here's your matrix, properly spaced:

```
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 53 207 256 207 231 348 348 348 231 244 244
240  33  67  33  56 133 133 133  56  33  33
460 107 200 107 122 324 324 324 122  33  33
167 340 396 340 422 567 567 567 422 442 442
167 367 307 367 433 336 336 336 433 158 158
160  20  37  20  31  70  70  70  31  22  22
200 307 393 307 222 364 364 364 222 286 286
 33 153 152 153 228 252 252 252 228  78  78
 93 140 185 140  58 118 118 118  58  44  44
  0   7  22   7  19  58  58  58  19   0   0
 67 153 241 153 128 297 297 297 128  39  39
 73 253 389 253 253 539 539 539 253  36  36
173 267 270 267 322 352 352 352 322 231 231
```

Comment: Awesome! You are absolutely right. In fact, i solved the problem in the same way you did (with the Munkres solution), is the only one that works. Thank you for your help, you just confirmed my theory :)

Comment: Your link is not valid anymore. Could you post your code in a public repository?

Comment: I actually have a comparison of various libraries (including my own code) here: https://github.com/Yay295/AssignmentProblemComparison

Answer (score 0):

Note in the link you provide section (2) that you add dummy rows or columns to make sure the matrix is square.

Now that you have a square matrix, there are a large number of different matchings which link together each row with its own column and vice versa. The solution, or solutions, is simply one of these matchings that has the lowest possible cost, so there should always be a solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i'm not being able to find any of these matchings that result in a future combination of 0 per column/row. Like the second matrix i put, where it is impossible to find any valid combination